# Navigate to another page with a button in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to navigate to a another page by clicking a button but it fails to work. What could be the problem. I am now learning angular 2 and it's a bit tough for me now.

```
//Routes/Path in a folder call AdminBoard

export const AdminRoutes: Routes =[

  {
    path: 'dashboard',

    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'Home'},
      {path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent},
      {path: 'Service', component: ServiceComponent},
      {path: 'Service/Sign_in', component:CustomerComponent}

    ]

  }

];

//Button is also in a different folder. Click button to navigate to this page           {path: 'Service/Sign_in', component:CustomerComponent}

  <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" ><a routerLink="/Service/Sign_in"> Add Customer</a></button>
```

Comment: try something like this: `<button class="btn btn-success pull-right" ><a [routerLink]="[ '.', 'Service/Sign_in' ]"> Add Customer</a></button>`

Answer (score 358, accepted):

Use it like this, should work:

```
 <a routerLink="/Service/Sign_in"><button class="btn btn-success pull-right" > Add Customer</button></a>
```

You can also use `router.navigateByUrl('..')` like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-outline pull-right" (click)="btnClick();"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</button>    

import { Router } from '@angular/router';

btnClick= function () {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/user');
};
```

#### Update 1

You have to inject `Router` in the constructor like this:

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }
```

only then you are able to use `this.router`. Remember also to import `RouterModule` in your module.

#### Update 2

Now, After Angular v4 you can directly add `routerLink` attribute on the button (As mentioned by @mark in comment section) like below (No "'/url?" since Angular 6, when a Route in RouterModule exists) -

```
 <button [routerLink]="'url'"> Button Label</button>
```

Comment: can i send some data with it ?

Comment: Not sure if things have changed since this was written, but as of October 2018, it seems you can just put the `[routerLink]` attribute directly on the `<button>` (which avoids some styling problems that can crop up when wrapping the button in an `<a>`)

Comment: So which way is cleanest? Is it better not to expose the route in the markup but keep it instead in the typescript file, or is the 'new' way with `[routerLink]` in the template the way to go?

Comment: it's up to you, IMO, there is no logic to hide your markup in the template as you are going to navigate to the user can see in the next page. Rest both are same i guess

Comment: At the first level `html file` where the component gonna be loaded has to have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag. please refer https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet#description for more details.

Comment: How about something that would look like `<button mat-button routerLink="['/users/', user.id]">View</button>` ? But it gives me an error. Is there a correct syntax for this ?

Comment: I'm finding in my application, that `<button [routerLink]="['/mypath', model.SomeVal ]">The button</button>` tries to navigate to:
`/mypath,99`, instead of:
`/mypath/99`
where model.SomeVal == 99.
I've tried all manner of combinations in the `routerLink` attribute value and nothing works as expected when you need to navigate to a parameterized route.

Comment: There must be some other problem with your code, as you posted code seems to be fine, Can you create a stackblize example for me to debug easily?

Comment: No need to use brackets here as we bind to a static String. Just use `routerLink="/url"`...

Comment: yeah, but earlier it has to be used with static strings as well.

Answer (score 51):

You can use routerLink in the following manner,

```
<input type="button" value="Add Bulk Enquiry" [routerLink]="['../addBulkEnquiry']" class="btn">
```

or use `<button [routerLink]="['./url']">` in your case, for more info you could read the entire stacktrace on github https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9471

the other methods are also correct but they create a dependency on the component file.

Hope your concern is resolved.

Comment: @Ronit Why not just: <button type="button" value="Add Bulk Enquiry" routerLink="../addBulkEnquiry" class="btn">? Why are you using the square brackets?

Comment: @AndyKing Because he is using an expression (an array as a value), `foo="boo"`  is like `[foo]="'boo'"`. Maybe you want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43633452/when-to-use-square-brackets-in-directives-inputs-and-when-not

Comment: I prefer this answer

Answer (score 16):

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-outline pull-right" (click)="btnClick();"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</button>


import { Router } from '@angular/router';

btnClick= function () {
        this.router.navigate(['/user']);
};
```

Comment: I did something similar like this at first (using router.navigate), then looked for other ideas, and now use routerLink as mentioned in other answers. I wonder which is better, or if it matters...

Answer (score 8):

There were many comments and answers which suggested to use `routerLink` - in different ways. I think, the following is the best way nowadays:

A relative **simple link**:

```
<button [routerLink]="/Service/Sign_in">Add Customer</button>
```

also possible with an array like

```
<button [routerLink]="['/Service', serviceId, 'Sign_in']">Add Customer</button>
```

to get a link to `/Service/2102/Sign_in` where `serviceID` is 2102.

---

If you have **query parameters** use:

```
<button [routerLink]="/Service/Sign_in" [queryParams]="{mode:'red'}">Add Customer</button>
```

and you receive a link to `/Service/Sign_in?mode=red`.

---

If your current url already has params (eg `/Service/foo?status=bar`), you can add **keep and add additional params** with:

```
<button [routerLink]="/Service/Sign_in" [queryParams]="{mode:'red'}" queryParamsHandling="merge">Add Customer</button>
```

which should give you a link to `/Service/foo?status=bar&mode=red`.

Or you can even **preserve** the existing ones (if some exist, eg if you are on `/Service/foo?mode=blue`) with:

```
<button [routerLink]="/Service/Sign_in" [queryParams]="{mode:'red'}" queryParamsHandling="preserve">Add Customer</button>
```

and you receive a link to `/Service/Sign_in?mode=blue`.

---

Some more modes to preserve the history or work with fragments are explained here: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Answer (score 4):

It is important that you decorate the router link and link with square brackets as follows:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/service']"> <button class="btn btn-info"> link to other page </button></a>
```

Where "*/service*" in this case is the path url specified in the routing component.

Comment: Wrapping a button in an anchor tag seems like bad practice

Answer (score 4):

There is one **significant difference** that no one seem to mention.

If you use `[routerLink]` on the button directly, or you navigate in your `.ts` file using `router`, the HTML will not show your button as a link.

This has several implications:

- it will not show the user the link that they are about to navigate to (oh hover, on the bottom left screen of the browser)

[URL Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quArL.png)

- they will not be able to open the link in new tab (using right click or control/command click
- this also has SEO implications as crawling engines would not recognise it as a link

In order to give the user the best experience possible I would strongly encourage you to use the format of wrapping your button in `a` tag:

```
<a [routerLink]="'/home'"><button>Home</button></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Having the router link on the button seems to work fine for me:

```
<button class="nav-link" routerLink="/" (click)="hideMenu()">
     <i class="fa fa-home"></i> 
     <span>Home</span>
</button>
```