# Angular 2 refresh same page

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Component that display a list of projects, with Edit and Delete buttons

If i click delete:

```
onDelete(projectName: string): void {
    this.projectService.deleteProject(projectName);

    this.router.navigate(['/projects']);
}
```

My router component:

```
export const projectListRouters: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    children: [
        {path: '', component: URLComponent},
        {path: 'login', component: Login},
        {path: 'projects', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: ProjectListComponent},

        {path: 'project/new/-', component: ProjectDetails, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: {oparationType: 'new'}},

        // otherwise redirect to home
        {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
    ],
},
```

];

My problem is that the ***this.router.navigate(['/projects'])*** does not refresh the list after deleting the project,

Comment: refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427405/navigate-to-another-page-with-a-button-in-angular-2

Comment: can you post your component that is routed to when you go to /projects?

Comment: my router component: added to the question

Comment: @user2143023, is onDelete function is in the same route i.e /projects?

Comment: no, i meant to include your ProjectListComponent. Also include the ProjectService, for completeness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you are redirecting to the same page.If that's the case, then please update your model say **projectList** that stores the list of project names.

If **deleteProject** is async call, then set **this.router.navigate(['/projects']);** in promise, otherwise just removing the element from **projectList** will do.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: updating the **projectList**  solved my problem, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There is now way to refresh component at all. You can create dummy component, redirect to it and redirect back to `/projects`.

After you make deletion of an item, you should just make a call to backend to retrieve list of projects as you did when you load component.

Answer (score 0):

Rather you can load your project list in subscribe of service.

```
delete() {

        this._service.delete(this.id).
            subscribe(x=> {
                // call your list here.
                this.projectList();
               }, error => {
                alert(error);
            });
    }
```