# Using more than one @input() decorator - ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm running a ionic 4 app

I created a message component, which loads accordingly to the error passed as `@Input` to it.

```
<control-messages [control]="saveUserForm.get('age')"></control-messages>
```

so it loads the `FormControl` validation and displays it's custom message as defined by me in it's service;

What I wanted to know, is if there's some way to send more than one property to the component, I wanted to dynamically decorate the `<p class='help'></p>` with a `success | warn | danger`

This is the component:

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'control-messages',
    template: `<p class="help" *ngIf="errorMessage !== null">{{errorMessage}}</p>`
  })
  export class ControlMessagesComponent {
    @Input() control: FormControl;

    constructor() { }

    get errorMessage() {
      for (const propertyName in this.control.errors) {
        if (this.control.errors.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) && this.control.touched) {
          return ValidationService.getValidatorErrorMessage(propertyName, this.control.errors[propertyName]);
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
```

How can I sent trough the parent another param to load in it's template as `{{color}}`, like

```
    template: `<p class="help {{color}}" *ngIf="errorMessage !== null">{{errorMessage}}</p>`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set input as many as you want:

parent html:

```
<control-messages 
    [control]="saveUserForm.get('age')"
    color="success">
</control-messages>
```

child ts:

```
export class ControlMessagesComponent {
    @Input() control: FormControl;
    @Input() color: string;
```

child html:

```
template: `<p class="help {{color}}" *ngIf="errorMessage !== null">{{errorMessage}}</p>`
```

But if you are checking the `success | warn | danger` from your formControl there is no need to send it from parent.

Comment: Why does the first decorator goes with `[]`, and the second one doesn't?
I believe that was the mistake I was making

Comment: decorators doesn't relate each other.

Comment: @MatheusBatista because `[color]=` expects a object and just a plain input like `color` expects a string. But when you cann still use it with `[]` like this `[color]="'red'"`

Comment: @MatheusBatista Thank you, I did'n understand his question. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43633452/when-to-use-square-brackets-in-directives-inputs-and-when-not

Answer (score 4):

You can add as many inputs as you want to e.g:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'control-messages',
    template: `<p class="help" [style.color]="color" *ngIf="errorMessage !== null">{{errorMessage}}</p>`
  })
  export class ControlMessagesComponent {
    @Input() control: FormControl;
    @Input() color: string;
 ...
```

Usage:

```
<control-messages 
    [control]="saveUserForm.get('age')"
    color="red">
</control-messages>
```