# Angular difference between [parameter]="value" and parameter="value"

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm working with Angular material and I'm facing the following problem.

In the example [here](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples), you can change the background using this code:

```
<mat-tab-group [backgroundColor]="backgroundColorToggle.value">
```

but for me, it didn't work.
Btw I'm not using the variable but just a string:

```
<mat-tab-group [backgroundColor]="primary">
```

In the end, I tried the following and it worked:

```
<mat-tab-group backgroundColor="primary">
```

In my own component, as an input parameter (`@Input()`) I can use both:
`<app-my-component [input]=..>` and `<app-my-component input=..>`

So what the difference between `[input]="value"` and `input="value"` and why in my component both worked and in Angular material it didn't.

Comment: that is called property binding when using `[bColor]="color"` and here, `color` must have component property.. if we simply want to pass string into then, we do not have to use property binding syntax just use `bColor="blue"` here, blue is simple string.

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43633452/when-to-use-square-brackets-in-directives-inputs-and-when-not

Comment: Thank you all for helping. I do agree that there are similar questions that could help me to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`backgroundColor` is a input property which expects a string. Square Bracket expects a property.

Therefore the syntax will be:

```
<mat-tab-group [backgroundColor]="'primary'">
```

or,

```
<mat-tab-group backgroundColor="primary">
```

or,

.ts

```
primary = 'primary';
```

.html

```
<mat-tab-group [backgroundColor]="primary">
```

Answer (score 1):

Using square brackets binds an attribute to a public property in your component.

This example would attempt to apply the value of the `primary` property in your component:

component.html

```
<mat-tab-group [backgroundColor]="primary">
</mat-tab-group>
```

component.ts

```
primary: string = 'red';
```

Whereas doing the same without square brackets sets the attribute to the literal value in the HTML.

```
<mat-tab-group backgroundColor="red">
</mat-tab-group>
```

These two examples are equivalent

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets imply binding, whereas omitting them does an attribute assignment (there's more to it, which I'll cover later). If you're doing a binding, the value in quotes has to be a JavaScript expression.

This line:

```
<mat-tab-group backgroundColor="primary">
```

simply assigns the value "primary" to the attribute `backgroundColor`. If the value "primary" doesn't exist, it depends on the component what to do with it.

This line:

```
<mat-tab-group [backgroundColor]="primary">
```

is a binding to a field named `primary`. It implies that in order to assign the attribute value, Angular will look for a field named `primary`, read its value and assign that instead. If the field named `primary` does not exist, it will assign a value of `undefined`. For example, if you have this:

```
primary = 'red';
```

then the second statement (with binding) will actually assign the value of "red" to your attribute, whereas the first statement (no binding) will still assign a value of "primary".

There are three additional things to note:

1. You can also do a binding by omitting the square brackets and using double braces instead, e.g. `<mat-tab-group backgroundColor="{{primary}}">`. The two are exactly equivalent, but the square bracket style is more familiar to everyone and you should always use it unless you have a good reason.
2. Because the binding accepts a JavaScript *expression*, you can supply more than a simple field, e.g. `<mat-tab-group [backgroundColor]="primary || secondary">`, will assign the value from the `secondary` field if `primary` is undefined. Also, `<mat-tab-group [backgroundColor]="shade + 'blue'">` will evaluate the field `shade` and add the value "blue" to it, yielding "lightblue" or "darkblue" depending on the value of `shade`.
3. If the property you're assigning to is boolean, then it becomes really easy to mess it up. `<my-comp active="true">` assigns a the text "true" to the `active` property, whereas `<my-comp [active]="true">` assigns the boolean value `true`. This may be an important distinction in your code, or may not. And since the two look so similar, I have personally missed that mistake for months. There are probably still a few lurking around somewhere.