# Syntax of Angular's reactive form controls in html

Tags: html, angular

```
<form [formGroup]="objForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <label formArrayName="orders" *ngFor="let order of getOrdersArray.controls; let i = index">
    <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
      {{ordersData[i].name}}
  </label>
   
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

This code works.

I want to understand since `formGroup` and `formControlName` are wrapped in `[]` (rectangular brackets), why is `formArrayName` not wrapped in []?

I didn't find any explanation in this page: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Please explain the reasoning behind that syntax.

Comment: Because it's not *bound*; it's not specific to forms, read up on the template syntax at https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax or run through the tutorial https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between parentheses, brackets and asterisks in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944749/what-is-the-difference-between-parentheses-brackets-and-asterisks-in-angular2)

Comment: @jonrsharpe am thankful for your helpful links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rectangular brackets in Angular are a type of "Binding Syntax". The attributes `formGroup` and `formControlName` are wrapped in brackets because they are binding to an expression that will be evaluated. In your example, `formGroup` is receiving the value of your `objForm` formGroup Object. `fomrControlName` will receive the value of the order currently pointed to by your index `i` in the *ngFor statement.

`formArrayName` is not being passed a variable expression that needs evaluation, instead you are providing it with a static value of "orders". Thus, the rectangular brackets are not necessary as no value binding is taking place.

For more information on Angular binding syntax, see [Angular Binding Syntax](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax#types-of-data-binding).

Also another helpful post on this [same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43633452/when-to-use-square-brackets-in-directives-inputs-and-when-not)