# Passing an object from an Angular 2 component to a custom directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have to pass a map (not a primitive - that works fine) from angular 2 component into a custom directive, but just keep getting a string - "[object Map]"

TS:

```
differences : Map<string,ObjectDifference>
```

HTML:

```
<input  type='text' differences={{differences}}> // I feel that's where the problem is
```

Directive code:

```
@Input('differences') differences : Map<string,ObjectDifference>
```

Value in directive at runtime:

```
differences: "[object Map]"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43633452/when-to-use-square-brackets-in-directives-inputs-and-when-not

Comment: [differences]=“differences” should do it..

Comment: Thank You, Mike, yes, that works - just posted my own answer - did not see yours

Answer (score 0):

And of course the right html is simply :

[differences]="differences"