# Passing props with and without [] brackets

Tags: angular

I am from vue/react background and learning Angular. I came across two syntaxeses of @Input so I am confused what do they mean e.g.

`<app-component color="red" [background]="yellow"></app-component>`

I understand `color="red"` but why do we pass [] around some props? what is the reason

Comment: This might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43633452/when-to-use-square-brackets-in-directives-inputs-and-when-not

Answer (score 2):

When you use the square brackets (`[background]="yellow"`), you are binding the value of the `yellow` variable (which should exist in your component). So, Angular looks for the value of the `yellow` variable, and inserts that value for you.

On the other hand, if you don't use the square brackets (`color="red"`), there isn't any variable interpolation (i.e. Angular doesn't look for a `red` variable in your component); you're simply giving the "color" HTML attribute the string "red".

[Here's the relevant documentation](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax) you can browse to understand this better.