# router link attribute within the button tag doesnt work

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am unable to navigate with router link attribute that is placed within the button tag. Here is my code,

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary"><a routerLink="/message-inbox">Inbox</a></button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent"><a routerLink="/sent">Sent</a></button>
    <a routerLink="/message-compose"><button color="warn">Compose</button></a>
```

Comment: Is the `<a>` element inside the button rendered?

Comment: @Karty There are more answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427405/navigate-to-another-page-with-a-button-in-angular-2/41427647)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I dint import the the router module. It worked after that,

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

Comment: That is very peculiar that you have to import this so you can use it on buttons. With `a` anchors it is not needed... weird? But thanks.

Comment: Thanks! It was my problem.

You could have clarified a bit your answer for new-comers specifiying the import + the declaration:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  exports: []
})
export class MyClass{ } ```

Comment: Amazing that after 7 years this is not mentioned in the official documentation: https://angular.dev/guide/routing/router-tutorial

Answer (score 42):

You can apply `routerLink` to the button directly. It doesn't have to be an `<a` element

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" routerLink="/message-inbox">Inbox</button>
```

Comment: I dint import the the router module. It worked after that

Comment: Same for me.. after importing it in the .ts file it started working for the button element (mat-button) in my case- even though other `<a` anchor links with routerLink worked fine on the same page

Answer (score 3):

Don´t nest anchors  inside buttons, it's not HTML5 compatible and doesn´t work in some browsers, like Firefox. It´s better to apply routerLink to the button directly, as Günter Zöchbauer said

Answer (score 1):

What if you try something like this:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary">
<a [routerLink]="['/message-inbox']">Inbox</a>
</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
<a [routerLink]="['/sent']">Sent</a>
</button>
    <a [routerLink]="['/message-compose']"><button color="warn">Compose</button></a>
```

Hope i helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

As was previously mentioned, `don't nest anchors inside buttons`, as it's not HTML5 compatible. In your case, since you're using Angular Material, it is ideal to do the following:

```
<a mat-raised-button color="primary" routerLink="/message-inbox">
  Inbox
</a>
```

This creates an anchor tag that is styled like a button. This comes with all the benefits of a link:

1. User can hover to preview link destination URL
2. User can right-click, which opens up many options to work with the link (Open in new tab/window, Copy link address, etc.)

From the [Angular Material Button docs](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview):

> Accessibility
>
> Angular Material uses native `<button>` and `<a>` elements to ensure
> an accessible experience by default. A `<button>` element should be
> used for any interaction that performs an action on the current page.
> An `<a>` element should be used for any interaction that navigates to
> another URL. All standard accessibility best practices for buttons and
> anchors apply to `MatButton`.