# Angular routing using buttons

Tags: javascript, angular

I have app.routes.ts:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomePageComponent } from '../layout/home/home-page/home-page.component';
import { LoginPageComponent } from '../layout/login/login-page/login-page.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomePageComponent,
    title: 'HomePage',
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginPageComponent,
    title: 'LoginPage',
  },
  {
    path: 'singup',
    component: LoginPageComponent,
    title: 'Signup',
  },
];
```

and

```
 <app-base-button-light
        title="Log in"
        routerLink="/login"
      ></app-base-button-light>
      <app-base-button-dark
        title="Sign in"
        routerLink="/login"
      ></app-base-button-dark>
```

if i type url/login this works, but if a click the button it doesnt work despite not having any error in console.
How to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Navigate to another page with a button in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427405/navigate-to-another-page-with-a-button-in-angular-2)

Comment: hi sir, thanks for the answer; I can make it work, i mean i can make it working using a tag or function, but i am using Angular 17 not Angular 2 and i want to use Angular in modern way and not overengeneerin thigs. The way i am implementing this i saw in another project and there it worked, and i dont understand why my example isnt working. This answer and solutions are outdated (7 years in framework development is a lot)

Answer (score 2):

You are likely missing `RouterLink` in the `imports` of your component.

You don't have any error because Angular only validates directives when there is a binding. In your case you set it as a static value.